# React when parent component re-render, I loose child state. What I'm missing?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm sure I'm missing something about how state works in React.

My component `GenericApiFilter` is a list of checkboxes, result of API call:

1. State `filters`: filters available, result of API call in `useEffect()`
2. State `selected`: list of selected filters by the user
3. Prop `onChange`: invoked when the selection changes

```ts
export const GenericFilter = ({
  apiUrl,
  apiParams,
  onChange = () => {},
}: GenericFilterProps) => {
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState<Filter[]>([]);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState<Filter[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(apiUrl, { params: apiParams }).then(res => setFilters(res.data));
  }, [apiUrl, apiParams]);

  return (
    <>
      {filters.map(filter =>
        <div key={filter.id}>
          <label>{filter.name} ({filter.count})</label>
          <input
            type='checkbox'
            checked={selected.includes(filter)}
            disabled={!filter.enabled}
            onChange={({ target: { checked } }) => {
              const selection = (checked ? [...selected, filter] : selected.filter(f => f !== filter));
              setSelected(selection);
              onChange(selection);
            }}
          />
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

The parent `FiltersPanel` uses the `GenericFilter`. **What's the problem?**

1. I check one or more checkbox and selection is retained
2. When I update the state calling `setSizeParams` (click on the button),i lost the selection: the filter re-renders without retaining the state

```ts
export const FiltersPanel= () => {
  const [sizeParams, setSizeParams] = useState({});

  return (
    <>
      <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={() => {
        setSizeParams(prev => ({ ...prev, time: Math.random() }));
      }}>Update size params</button>

      <GenericFilter apiUrl='/api/filter/size' apiParams={sizeParams} />
    </>
  );
};
```

What I'm missing here?

Comment: reproducible example would be nice

Comment: Working on it. It's not easy as I can't find fake API's

Comment: what do you mean data is lost did you console.log `selected`?

Comment: Wait 5 minutes, I've simplified the example.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava I've updated the question. I've found the problem happens even without multiple components but just calling `setSizeParams`.

Comment: what happens? did you log `selected`?

Comment: `console.log(selection)` inside the filter component works. When I check/uncheck it gets updated. When I call `setSizeParams` the filter component re-render and selection is lost. I'm pretty new to React and I'm sure I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not about React, is about JS:

```js
selected.filter(f => f !== filter));
```

Here you are comparing *objects*, and this will match just if you are comparing *the same* objects. As soon as you render the component again, those object change and the comparison will always return false.

Solution: work with *primitive values* (e.g. the `id`), and it should work:

```js
return (
    <>
      {filters.map((filter) => (
        <div key={filter.id}>
          <label>
            {filter.name} ({filter.count})
          </label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={selected.includes(filter.id)}
            disabled={!filter.enabled}
            onChange={({ target: { checked } }) => {
              const selection = checked
                ? [...selected, filter.id]
                : selected.filter((f) => f !== filter.id);
              setSelected(selection);
              onChange(selection);
            }}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem

```
        checked={selected.includes(filter)}
```

You are checking with `includes` against an *object* `filter`.
But when effect fires again in that component, the new filter objects arrive, hence that above `includes` check won't work anymore.

So you should use something like an `id` instead of storing object references.

Comment: You made my day, thank you! Actually, also the solution was also to use filter.id check proposed by @moonwave99